# Should I use a TSQL trigger add records to an insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

We are logging data about the utilization of tools in a factory by scraping their log files. They all have thier own formats but generally speaking the tools all generate data that can trivially be converted to this:

```
MachineID    StartTime             DurationSeconds  Operaton
1            2018-10-22 01:30:00   60               Drill
1            2018-10-22 01:31:00   60               Drill
1            2018-10-22 01:59:59   7202             Drill
```

Having multiple records within an hour boundary is OK.

Data in this form makes analytics cumbersome because we need to report data at one hour groups (e.g. a group by StartTime rounded to the hour to report hourly utilization).  This is not possible with unbounded durations. Our current code (in .net) maps the above log file record to the database like this:

```
MachineID    StartTime             DurationSeconds  Operaton
1            2018-10-22 01:30:00   60               Drill
1            2018-10-22 01:31:00   60               Drill
1            2018-10-22 01:59:59   1                Drill
1            2018-10-22 02:00:00   3600             Drill
1            2018-10-22 03:00:00   3600             Drill
1            2018-10-22 04:00:00   1                Drill
```

This was a little tricky to get right in our current system and I'd rather not specify this to vendors and muck with everybody getting it right.  Having them just write their "raw" start/duration data would be easier for everybody.

How can I use a trigger to convert the general (start/duration) log data to the chunked data we want? It seems like a trigger could iterate over DurationSeconds and the chunk data in the trigger.

Alternatively, I guess they could write raw data to a table and I could read the data and write chunked data to another table.

The trigger seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: Since you have start and duration in seconds, I would think that a calculated column would produce a lot less grief in the long run.

Comment: the trouble with the trigger idea is that you cannot guarantee you'd get all the rows in one set when the trigger fires.  OTOH you could process what you get, then add a new row if needed or update an existing row if you already added it.

Comment: You could reuse (mostly) your existing .net code using a CLR trigger.

Comment: @RyanB. I'm not sure how a calculated column helps.  Such a column won't add rows when needed.

Comment: @user1443098 What do you mean I'd get all the rows?  I'm not under a constraint that I must have all of the data in a single row for a single hour.  Many of our tools run for very short durations.  The query we analyze with does a group by, rounded by hour on our chunked table. (I updated the example)

Answer (score 0):

I went with a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddEquipmentUtilization] 
    @id_equip INT,
    @start_time DateTime,
    @job_seconds INT     
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @min int;
    declare @sec int ;
    declare @sec_in_hour int;
    declare @sec_to_add int;

    --Write chunks of data to the table in pieces upto the #of seconds left in the hour
    WHILE @job_seconds > 0
        begin 

            -- Number of seconds left in current hour (partial hour OK)
            set @min = DATEPART(minute,@start_time);
            set @sec = DATEPART(second,@start_time);
            set @sec_in_hour = (59-@min)*60 + 60-@sec

            -- Add everything left in hour or the full hour  
            if @job_seconds < @sec_in_hour
                set @sec_to_add = @job_seconds
            else
                set @sec_to_add = @sec_in_hour

            insert into Test (StartTime,Seconds,Id) Values (@start_time,@sec_to_add,@id_equip)

            -- Invariant: add/subtract sec_to_add
            set @start_time = DateAdd(second,@sec_to_add,@start_time)
            set @job_seconds= @job_seconds-@sec_to_add
        end
END
```